# Inline if with else

Tags: ruby

I realize that it's not valid ruby but what would be the technical hurdles to implement the below functionality into the Ruby core language (of say v2.3)?

```
variable = 1 if condition else -1
```

I'd also like to allow the following for more generic use.

```
variable = { 1 } if condition else { -1 }
```

I'm very open to requiring an "end" at the end.

I get that a ternary can easily accomplish this but I'm looking for a more readable inline-if that allows an else.
I get that I can make a function which does this via any number of styles but I'd prefer to have it as readable as possible.

Thanks.

EDIT: I hate editing questions for obvious reasons.
In response to the question of how the generic option is more ruby-esque, see the below example (I needed newlines).

```
variable = { 
  operation_one
  operation_two
  ...
  SUCCESS_STATUS_CODE
} if loaded_dependencies else { 
  do_detailed_logging
  FAILURE_STATUS_CODE
}

if variable then
  it_worked
else
  explain_why
end
```

Comment: In your example, does `variable` get set to `1` when `condition` is `true`, and when `condition` is `false`, `variable` gets set to `-1`?

Comment: yes but that's not valid ruby.

Comment: I know, I just wanted to make sure I understood your intention. Why not just use one of `variable = condition ? 1 : -1` or `variable = if condition then 1 else -1 end`?

Comment: Why? Just use the conditional operator. That's usually the most readable way but you could write `variable = if condition then 1 else -1 end` if you don't want to.

Comment: I'm very aware that ternary makes this simple but it doesn't seem very ruby-esque in terms of syntax.

Comment: thanks for the response cremno but from the parsing side, my suggested format is distinctly different (so it's possible to implement) which would eliminate the need for the "then" and potentially the "end" while still following the current `variable = 1 if condition`

Comment: the `cond ? true_path : false_path` is ternary syntax. `if cond then true_path else false_path end` is just a regular if statement. What is not ruby-esque about an if statement?

Comment: I'd like to hear why your more generic example is more ruby-esque.

Comment: Why don't you grab the source from Github and try to add your proposed syntax?

Comment: I think the proposed grammar is supposed to be like "*foo is 1 if blah else it's 2*", but English isn't the best template for clarity. As code `foo = 1 if blah else 2` reads really weird. I initially read it as two different statements: `foo = 1` and a separate conditional `if blah then ? else 2`. `foo = 1 if blah` works because it's simple: do this if that. Once you add in another clause you have two clashing patterns. The two possible values of `foo` are at opposite ends of the statement. Then it appears to follow the `if condition this else that` but `this` is in front of the `if`.

Comment: Your example of use illustrates why this will be hard to read. You have two complicated assignments split by their condition. They don't even look like assignments, they look like code blocks... I guess `variable` ends up with the status code? The example should be dealt with by exceptions, it eliminates the need for that status variable: `begin load_deps; thing1; thing2; it_worked; rescue do_detailed_logging; explain_why; end`. If we're going to talk about what is Ruby-esque, exceptions are Ruby-esque. Making the user remembering to check for error flags is to be avoided.

Comment: @muistooshort Thanks for the suggestion. That's what I'm trying to do but I am unsure of where would be the correct place in the code.  I need to modify the translation of the lex symbols for modifier_if, and modifier_unless but I can't find where they are implemented.  Worst case I could make a modifier_if_else and a modifier_unless_else but that might lead to code duplication.  I could also try to implement it as a modifier_else but I can't find code where the translation of modifier_if into bytecode happens in the source.

Comment: Also to everyone, I didn't ask if it was a good idea (that's up to the maintainers).  I ask for the technical hurdles as I intend to create a pull request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your example, while it seems readable to you, has too many ambiguities in other cases.

Not to mention that ruby has a way to do this, and it's the ternary operator.  To say that your example is more ruby-like, is almost like wondering why the wheelbase of the Ford Mustang wasn't longer, and that it would be more "Mustang-like" if it was.

But here are some issues with your proposal, starting from your example:

```
variable = { 1 } if condition else { -1 }
```

Here you've given your "if else" bit a lower precedence than the "=".

In other words:

```
variable = ({ 1 } if condition else { -1 })
```

That's a serious problem, because it breaks the currently allowed:

```
variable = 1 if condition
```

The precedence for that statement is:

```
(variable = 1) if condition
```

And that's important.  No assignment happens if the condition is false.

This can be a really big deal, for example if the lvalue (left side) actually has side-effects.  For example:

```
var[0] = 1 if condition
```

The lookup for "var[0]" is a method in whatever class object var is, and while [] doesn't usually have side-effects, it *can* - and now you are going to do those side effects even if the condition is false.

And I won't even get into:

```
variable = { 1 } if condition if condition2 else { -1 }
```

But if you don't like it, you can always write your own language and see what happens!

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I don't see an issue with side effects since you're being explicit that an assignment will happen regardless of the condition.  In my example, It's defined that an assignment will always happen so the side effect will always happen. The only odd thing I see when implementing this is that the condition must be completely executed before the assignment operation as to maintain backwards compatibility.  The last example would expand to `variable = ({1} if condition (nil if condition2 else {-1}))` by lexing rules that I've found in source (if it were parsed as valid).

Comment: Since the `else` always modifies the `if` closest in the token stream provided the absence of `end`.

Comment: Having the side effect happens means that:
'a[0]=42 if <cond>'

Is totally different from

'a[0]=42 if <cond> else 43' - the first does not and cannot have side effects without completely changing the nature of ruby.